# Symbolically Minimizing a Max function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I'm having a tough time with seemingly simple symbolic Minimization/Maximization in Mathematica. I would like to use the Maximize function to work on some unknown random variables and so use min/max functions that depend on the value of these random variables. The maximization was not working on some pretty simple cases so I boiled it down even further.

The simplest case of this phenomenon is as follows

```
Minimize[{Max[X, Z], X \[Element] Reals, X > 0, Z \[Element] Reals},
Z]
```

which returns itself. But of course, if X is a real number and greater than zero, it is trivial that you can set Z to <=X and minimize the function. And of course setting X to any specific number returns that, but I'm unsure why the more general problem doesn't work here? I'm thinking some insight into why will help in my more complex problems.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: This is rather tricky to answer. Unfortunately I do not have much time for that now. Bottom line is that mathematica obviously cannot handle the `Max` function symbolically in conjunction with its symbolic optimisation capabilities. In practice you will do some numerical computations anyway and for that you have many possibilities to treat the max function. You could for example take a smooth approximation for it and use differential calculus, etc..